# Dependency Resolver using Ninject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am always getting the error

`No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

when I execute the codes below.

It must be something to do with my ninject modules.
What seems to be the problem here?

Controller

```
  public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserService _service; 

        public AccountController(IUserService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
    }
```

Service Layer

```
 public class UserService : ServiceBase<User>, IUserService
    {
        public UserService(IRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }

    }

    public interface IUserService : IService<User>
    {
    }
```

Repository

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
    {

    }

    public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
    {

    }
```

Ninject ----
ServiceModule

```
 public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
           Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
}
}
```

RepositoryModule

```
 public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
           Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
}
}
```

Setup

```
 public static void SetupDependencyInjection()
        {
            // Create Ninject DI kernel
            var kernel = CreateKernel();

            // Tell ASP.NET MVC 3 to use our Ninject DI Container
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }

        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var modules = new INinjectModule[]
                              {
                                 new ServiceModule(),
                                 new RepositoryModule()
                              };

            return new StandardKernel(modules);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have have registered:

```
Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
```

But you are referring to the base `IRepository` interface in `UserService`:

```
    public UserService(IRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
```

So Ninject won't know how to construct a generic `IRepository`. You need to Bind a implementation for `IRepository`. Or use `IUserRepository` in `UserService`:

```
    public UserService(IUserRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
```